# Get file using file name. there may be multiple files with similar names _1, _2 etc

Tags: c#, file

I am using the following to get the size of a file

```
FileInfo(filePath).Length
```

which of course works.

The file path is something like

```
Live\Sites\User\297387\XYZ - ABC
```

but an issue arises when the file is a duplicate

```
Live\Sites\User\297387\XYZ - ABC_2
```

Is there a way I can get the latest version of the file that name matches

```
Live\Sites\User\297387\XYZ - ABC
```

So I have the following files

```
Live\Sites\User\297387\XYZ - ABC
Live\Sites\User\297387\XYZ - ABC_1
Live\Sites\User\297387\XYZ - ABC_2
```

and I need to get the latest one that matches

```
Live\Sites\User\297387\XYZ - ABC
```

Comment: You have two files with the same name in same folder ?

Comment: Sorry, No I have files with names like Live\Sites\User\297387\XYZ - ABC, Live\Sites\User\297387\XYZ - ABC_1, Live\Sites\User\297387\XYZ - ABC_2

Comment: get all files =>pregmatch(filename) => fileinfo("lastmodified") sort by ascending then grap the last

Comment: Why are these duplicates, for me the file names are different. Specify aduplicate file-name first. Are those files all in the same directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Path` class and LINQ:

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
var latestFile = new DirectoryInfo(dir)
    .EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Where(file => file.Name.StartsWith(fileName))
    .OrderByDescending(file => file.LastAccessTime)
    .First();
long len = latestFile.Length;
```

If you dont want to check the last access time but the number behind `_` you can use this query:

```
var latestFile = new DirectoryInfo(dir)
    .EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Where(file => file.Name.StartsWith(fileName))
    .Select(file => 
    {
        int index = file.Name.LastIndexOf('_');
        string vStr = "0";
        if(index >= 0)
            vStr = file.Name.Substring(index + 1);
        int version;
        if(!int.TryParse(vStr, out version))
            version = 0;
        return new { file, version }; 
    })
    .OrderByDescending(xFile => xFile.version)
    .Select(xFile => xFile.file)
    .First();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.created%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
watcher.Path = " Live\Sites\User\297387\XYZ";
watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);


private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
   Console.WriteLine("File: " +  e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This LinQ Query get the last file in Directory:

```
var lastFile = (from a in directoryInfo.EnumerateFiles()
                        orderby a.CreationTime descending
                        select a).FirstOrDefault();
```

or

```
var lastFile = (from a in directoryInfo.EnumerateFiles()
                        orderby a.CreationTime
                        select a).LastOrDefault();
```

Comment: This won't check for a regex equality on the file names, simply get the newest file in the directory

Answer (score 1):

This is my "cleanest" first-to-mind solution:

```
string regx = "file"; // replace this with your actual "base" file name
var f = Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\") // replace with your directory path
    .Where(fn=>
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(fn, regx, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    .Select(fn=>new FileInfo(fn))
    .Aggregate( (f1,f2) => f1.LastWriteTime> f2.LastWriteTime? f1 : f2);
```

This will match all files in C:\ that has the word file in it - then select the most recently written file.